# Java automation testing tool with recording program execution for regression testing

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, netbeans, aop

Searching for any free tool capable doing this. It's not import if it's for eclipse, netbeans or standalone tool, but I prefer eclipse or netbeans plugin. What I need is **record program execution for the following regression testing** of java programs, but it can't work via writing test, but via recording program execution flow.

**Explanation of question:** I'm building java profiling tool mostly through AOP aproach and I must first run program for identifing  pointcuts in code execution flow for testing so I need record it and after that its helpfull for regression testing of recorded execution flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently came across a great tool. And I think it's exactly what you need.

It's **Chronon**

> **Chronon** records the execution flow and variables while **running** the program.

**Chronon Recording Server**

Chronon records every change made by every single line of code in your program while it is executing, from the very beginning to the end of the program. The recording is saved to a file and can then be transferred across machines and also shared amoung team members

**Chronon Time Traveling Debugger**

Team members can use the Chronon Recording file to play back the entire execution of the Java program on their desktops and find the root cause of any issues instantly.

http://chrononsystems.com/what-is-chronon/technology#video/0/

---

> Edited: Free for students.

Comment: It's exactly what I need and it's free for students, so Thank You very much!